# Able to locate element but cannot click on it

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click on a button that downloads a `csv` file. I am able to find it but I cannot click on it.

```
url = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/acyqu01/gamelog/2015/"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='advanced_div']/div[2]/div/span[6]")
elem.click()
```

`ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`

I've also tried this:

```
action_chain = webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver)
action_chain.click(elem)
action_chain.perform()
```

I've noticed the source code has a transparent font. Does that mean it is hidden? I read something about executing a java script to click on it. But, I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I changed the answer- no need of js, set ff browser profile to save csv automatically hehe!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `DIV` that has `id=advanced_div` is hidden. You can see the HTML for that tag below, note the `display:none` style.

```
<div id="advanced_div" style="display: none;">
```

While looking at the page I noticed that there is a "Switch to Advanced Game Log" link on the page and I clicked it. When I did that, that `DIV` became visible which meant that the CSV link that you want is now visible.

So to do this with code, you will want to click the same link and then click the CSV link you want. You can use the XPath you have in your code ... or... you can use `find_element_by_link_text()` which I think makes this task easier. The code below should work.

```
url = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/acyqu01/gamelog/2015/"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Switch to Advanced Game Log").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("CSV").click()
```

My only concern is that the CSV link text might not be unique. If that's the case, you can use your XPath as below.

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Switch to Advanced Game Log").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='advanced_div']/div[2]/div/span[6]").click()
```

In general, what you want to do when you write automation is to figure out what the user needs to do on the page and then write code that does the same thing. So, when you come across some element that is hidden, as in this case, figure out how the user would make it visible and then do that with code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement wait whereas dom loads-below is the full working code for me. It automatically sets firefox profile an avoids csv file save prompt and saves csv into a defined folder, in this case that folder is the `Desktop\downloads`

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", r"C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop\downloads")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")


url = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/acyqu01/gamelog/2015/"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver,1000).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='basic_div']")))
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='basic_div']/div[2]/div/span[6]")
elem.click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='basic_div']/div[2]/div/span[6]")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();',elem)
```

Comment: That might accomplish the task but it's not how the user would do it. It's using JavaScript to get around the invisibility of the element. Take a look at my answer.